# How to get the configurations of current running XC Test plan programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xctest, xcode11

**Problem Statement:**

My Test flow will depend on the type of configuration that is currently running for a test plan.
I want to get the configuration name and environment variable entries of the currently running test plan in Xcode, so that according to the configuration I can decide what action to perform in a particular test.

Eg.

I have a test plan **XYZ.xctestplan** with two configurations "A" and "B". I want to get the environment variable entries that are set in the currently running configuration of the **XYZ.xctestplan**
According to these environment variables, I will decide which button should be clicked in my UI test.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the environment variables in, say named "359TZ", like this:

```
    NSString *key = @"359TZ";
    NSString *tz359 = [NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment objectForKey:key];
```

Please note that IIRC, you get the environment variables in a configuration when you run from Xcode, but not when you run using xcodebuild.  YMMV.

Comment: What do you mean by the above "NOTE" statement. Please clarify it more. means if I run my test plan using xcodebuild, then I won't be able to get the environment variables?

Comment: As of this morning, it looks like it does obtain environment variables with xcodebuild, but it does not respect any custom location provided by a .gpx file.  I'll have to look a little more into this.

Comment: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/1678  Apparently a long standing issue

Comment: In my case, I am only dealing with the env. variables. so I think it should work for me.